# Is it just my phone or has the mobile version changed?

Tags: discussion, support

I'm currently using the mobile version on my Nokia C6. Have Stack Exchange changed the view of all the mobile sites? Or is it just my phone. If it's my phone, I'm sorry for asking, but I just want to know?

The layout changed like in place of the votes up and down it shows _s(vote up) and _s(vote down) and everything is centered? Maybe it's just for older phones

Comment: Checked SO with my iphone and everything looks familiar, didn't saw anything new.

Comment: Looks about the same to me...

Comment: Relevant: [Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) (if you're on a Nokia C6, I suspect your browser is not one of these)